# How do I dodge overlapping line/polygon layers so that each is visible in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, symbology

I have 3 separate polygon layers that often overlap (image below). How do I change the symbology in QGIS to have them parallel to one another and not overlapping? (as shown in the second image below).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that with the style property window you can start by prioritizing the display of the layers (capt 1), then shift the layers relative to each other if necessary (capt 2)
[image]

[image]